# My loop is not executing a particular iteration

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

The second iteration `1 2 1` is being skipped by my loop:

[image: This is the code]

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enten number");
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int a= sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++) {
        int k=1;
        for(int j=1;j<=a-i;j++) {
            System. out. print ("  ");
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++) {
            if(j<=i) {
                System.out.print(k+++" ");}
            else {
                while(k>=1)
                    System.out.print(k--+" ");
            }

        }System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image ([edit] your question). Have you stepped through it with the debbugger?

Comment: @TiiJ7 Tell the questioner not to post code as an image and you might get the code as text for one question; teach SO to do OCR would... ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the 3rd *for* loop replace the *if* statement `if(j<=i)` with `if(j<i)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enten number");
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int a= sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++) {
        int k=1;
        for(int j=1;j<=a-i;j++) {
            System. out. print ("  ");
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++) {
            if(j<i) {
                System.out.print(k+++" ");}
            else {
                while(k>=1)
                    System.out.print(k--+" ");
            }

        }System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will print correct sequence but it affects the format. Format is slightly off

Answer (score 0):

This is same as [Radhe Ankit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62300330/2106815) answer but i have fixed issue with formatting.
Added a separate control variable named `r` for printing number of spaces.

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
            System.out.println( "enten number" );
            Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int r = a * 2 - 1;
            for ( int i = 1; i <= a; i++ ) {
                int k = 1;
                for ( int j = 1; j <= r - i; j++ ) {
                    System.out.print( " " );
                }
                for ( int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++ ) {
                    if ( j < i ) {
                        System.out.print( k++ + " " );
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print( k-- + " " );
                    }

                }
                System.out.println();
                r = r - 1;
            }
        }
```

Below is the sample output for number

> 7

as input

```
            1 
          1 2 1 
        1 2 3 2 1 
      1 2 3 4 3 2 1 
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
  1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```